# Grunt watch two separate LESS files and output into two separate CSS files

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm using LESS for the my main app and also need a separate CSS file that isn't part of the main app. I'm trying to add a new source and destination to my existing grunt watch task

```
less: {
    development: {
        options: {

            paths: ["path/to/less", "// path/to/2nd.less??"],
            yuicompress: true
        },
        files: {
            "path/to/build.css": ["path/to/less"]
        },
        //other src destination here?
        files: {
           "path/to/2nd.css": ["path/to/2nd.less"]
          }
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    files: ["path/to/less", "path/to/2nd.less"],
    tasks: ["less"]
}
```

Comment: Add a new target http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @jgillich for pointing me towards the docs. Solution:

```
less: {
    development: {
        options: {
        paths: ["path/to/less"],
        yuicompress: true
    },
    files: {
        "path/to/build.css": ["path/to/less"]
    },
  }
},
    2nd: {
options: {
 // same as above but with new paths
    }
  }
},
watch: {
    files: ["path/to/less", "path/to/2nd.less"],
    tasks: ["less"]
}
```